# How to send a message on specific date through GCM push notification?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android development and now i am working on GCM push notification. I have implemented the GCM notification successfully. Now, i want to know how to implement this functionality that sender send a message but it should be received by receiver after some days.

--> For example second user's birthday is on 15 August and first user send message on 2nd August but it should be received on his/her birthday on 15th August on receiver's account. Is there any techniques to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this logic in your server. You should keep a record with messages sent on your server database. Then use this record to send the push notifications on their birthday!

Comment: but how i can handle this on server through php? i mean how i can handle that this message should be send on that date @Ruchira

Comment: Hi Bebo. That's up to you to decide! I'm not a php guy, I can only give a solution from an artitectural perspective.  Im unable to give a source code solution. Depending on how you store your database you can maybe run a daily task which will iterate through your database and see whose birthday it is. Then go and check if there are messages for him. If so, send GCM messages. Got it?

Comment: yes , now i got your logic. thank you very much @Ruchira